# Was the number of Tom Riddle's room an allusion to Chapter 27?

Tags: harry-potter

In the film *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* (2009) when Dumbledore instructs Harry in private pensieve lessons that delve into Voldemort's past, we learn not only that Dumbledore meets Tom Riddle for the first time in Wool's Orphanage, but also that Tom Riddle's room number is 27. I'm curious if, more than a random number, the filmmakers used that number as a nod to Chapter 27 of Rowling's eponymous novel, in which we find out that a certain character dies.

[image: Still image from Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince (2009)]

Comment: You can use a spoiler tag to say who dies.

Comment: Pretty sure we can stop worrying about spoilers on a 20 year old multi-billion pound franchise.